# how to use red5recorder with red5 server or wowza streaming server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, actionscript, red5, red5-recorder

how can I use red5recorder with red5 server or wowza streaming server for recording live video stream on ubuntu 14.04.

I couldn't find any proper documentation either related to red5-server or red5recorder. After searching a lot I found a way to install red5-server and setup red5recorder as follows.

**Installing `red5server`**

Set-up red5 server on my local machine having ubuntu 14.04 by downloading zip files from  -

```
https://github.com/Red5/red5-server
```

Extracted and copied it to the directory `/usr/share/` and changed its name to `red5`. Executed `red5.sh` in the terminal. It successfully installed red5server on my machine. Following links were useful while setting it up -

http://www.yourhowto.net/install-red5-media-server-ubuntu-debian/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-red5-on-ubuntu-12-10

After the installation you can start red5-server by the command `sudo service red5-server start`. Now go to browser an type the URL `http://localhost:5080` which would launch the red5 server.

**Setting up `red5recorder`**

Download the recorder from the URL http://www.red5-recorder.com/

Extract and Copy it to your `www` folder

Open the following file `/red5recorder/bin-debug/red5recorder.html` in the browser.

It might give error `"Error: rtmp://127.0.0.1/red5server not found"`

So to resolve it edit the file, and add server path after line 91 approx `"FlashVars", "server=rtmp://localhost"` inside else-if condition.

`"FlashVars", "server=rtmp://localhost"` is in my case, as I have installed red5server on my local machine. You can use demo URL such as - `rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod`

Useful links -  http://www.red5-recorder.com/params.php , http://www.hdwplayer.com/rtmp-streaming-video-player/

=========================================================================

**After all this I have a question, streaming started working fine in red5recorder, but video is not getting recorded. How can I make it work ? and how can I change filename ? And where does file gets saved ?**

=========================================================================

I did searched for this also, and created a new application in `red5server` `webapps` directory with the name `red5recorder` having two sub folders `streams` and `WEB-INF` as described here - http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/newapp.html

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a demo `oflaDemo-r4472-java6.war` from the URL - http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/ to the directory `{RED5_HOME}/webapps` and then extracted using the command **`jar -xvf oflaDemo.war`**.

Then restart the red5-server using the command `sudo service red5-server restart`. Now one of the demo should work from the given URL `http://localhost:5080/demos/`, mainly `oflaDemo` would work.

Now change the permission of all subfolders inside `/webapps` directory to `777`. start your demo application and video should get recorded in the directory `/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/`

**Edit-** This link may be useful https://serverfault.com/questions/215997/install-red5-demos-via-installer-or-within-war-file-manually